# Generate string of random number that includes some number and exclude some number

Tags: javascript

I have a problem about generating string in javascript.
I have an array of number that string should contains atleast 1, and 1 number(up to 7 digits) that must not contains in a string. String length must be 7.

```
var incNumber = ["15","51","14","41","55","39","23"];
var exclude = ... //input from user
```

I tried to generate it by random select from array, random position and random other number around selected number. Then check if string contains excluded number, generate it again.

```
//random select number
var getRandom = incNumber[Math.floor(Math.random() * incNumber.length)];

//random position of number 
var position = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);

//length of other string after selected number
var afterlen = 7 - (position+2);

//genNum(...) is my function that use to generate string of number in specific length.
var nstr = genNum(position)+getRandom+genNum(afterlen);

while (nstr.includes(exclude)) {
nstr = genNum(position)+getRandom+genNum(afterlen);
}
```

but doing this take too long time or sometimes freeze my browser. How should I fix it.?

edited: It's my homework about phonenumber.
final string should be like "37915002"

Comment: What are example exclusions? Are they words, e.g., "apple", "bob", "cheese", or are they single characters like "a", "b", "c"? Or possibly (simple) combination of characters like "ab", "ac", "bb"?

Comment: any number e.g.., "1","12","156789"

Comment: So, to be clear (because I apparently misunderstood the question initially) - the string generated would be entirely numeric, e.g., "1234567". It has to include some given numbers but the user can also exclude some. The excluded should never occur in the generated string. So if you have to include, say, `21`, and the user wants to exclude `32`, you shouldn't generate a string that, for example, starts with `321`. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that correct. Sorry for not clear question. I'm not good at English.

Comment: No worries, it's early for me, so the coffee hasn't fully kicked in yet. I read it wrong and I wanted to make sure I didn't continue reading it wrong :)

Comment: Soo wait I think I read it wrong too... Let's say you have the `include = [1, 10, 20]` now I exclute "1" should I now be able the get the "10" in the string or should the "1"  be removed and just the "0" added?

Comment: Oh, I forgot to think about that. I think "10" should not be selected(because 1 is excluded). (My home work didn't write about this situation too.)

Comment: But myhomework say that if user excludes all incNumber (by some pattern of number that can match all incNumber), then I can alert the user about it.

Comment: So should the 0 also not be selected?

Comment: Yes.Only 20 can be selected because user only exclude 1. (if include = [1,10,20])

Comment: I'll work on a solution this is some brain food :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edited my code again**

Does that now match your needs? It has got pretty messy and I'm not sure if it's correct (I'm never sure.. xD) hope you can get some inspiration though.

```js
// Variables
var initialList = ["100", "5", "19", "88", "10", "90"];
var excludeList = ["9", "10"];
var resultLength = 7;
var finalString = "";

// Create a third final array that is filtered
var finalList = initialList.filter(element => {
  let shouldBeIncluded = true;
  excludeList.forEach(excluder => {
    Array.from(excluder).forEach(excluderFragment => {
      if (element.includes(excluderFragment)) shouldBeIncluded = false;
    });
  });
  if (shouldBeIncluded) return true;
});

// Check if all were excluded
if (finalList.length == 0) {
  // Do error handling here
} else {
  // Create the list
  for (let i = 0; i < resultLength; i++) {
    finalString += finalList[Math.floor(Math.random() * finalList.length)];
  }
  // Shorten the list because multiple digits values
  finalString = finalString.slice(0, 7);
  console.log(finalString);
}
```

Comment: Your answer is almost match my need. Thankyou for inspiration for the solution.

Comment: No problem :) always here to help :3

Answer (score 0):

You could start by filtering the unwanted number from the incNumber and doing everything the same way but on the new array

```
var incNumber = ["15","51","14","41","55","39","23"];
var exclude = "12";

var filteredNumbber =incNumber.filter(number=> number!==exclude);
var random = filteredNumbber[Math.floor(Math.random() * filteredNumbber.length)];
```

if we assume exclude is not a value but instead an array of values you would change the formula to

```
var incNumber = ["15","51","14","41","55","39","23"];
var exclude = ["15"];

var filteredNumbber =incNumber.filter(number=> !exclude.includes(number));
var random = filteredNumbber[Math.floor(Math.random() * filteredNumbber.length)];
```

as some people suggested random variable may end up as `undefined` if we exclude all the numbers inside of incNumber, if that was the case we should add an additional check in case that happens

`if (random!==undefined) var nstr = genNum(position)+random+genNum(afterlen);`

Comment: That risks excluding all mandatory numbers. Consider `incNumber = ["12", "23", "34"]` and then `exclude = ["12", "23", "34"]`. Which is a bit contradictory. To be honest, I'm not sure what should happen then. But that would be a problem since you'd be getting index zero of the new array that is empty which yields `undefined`.

Comment: I would assume that returning `undefined` as the result of getting random number from an empty array would be a desired behaviour

Comment: I'm with @KrzysztofKrzeszewski here. In case of "just positive numbers" we could also return -1. Or return false. (ofc for that it would have to be a function)

Comment: Well, it depends. If you were to concatenate it as a string, that would give you the string `"undefined"`. So, it may be fine but it could be misused. At any rate, one should be aware of the possibility in order to not be surprised. It could be totally valid that if you have mandatory numbers and they all get excluded, so no mandatory number would be included, just a string or random numbers (that avoid the exclusions).

Comment: Well definitely don't return the string `"undefinded"` you of course have to catch that. Otherwise we would have some messy output

Comment: @Elias well, the problem is that you don't return the *string* "undefined". You could simply return `undefined`. Consider the following `generatedString += getFilteredRandom()` - if the function returns the *value* `undefined`, it'd be cast into the *turned* into the string `"undefined"` during the concatenation. If you're not aware that you might accidentally return index zero of an empty array (which OP might very well be), then you'd suddenly have said messy output.

Comment: Yes... I think we're talking away from each other xD I meant to catch that before starting the random part... :D like `if(list.length == 0) {alert("what ever"); return;}`